# Debugging into COM from MSTest

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, com, mstest

Trying to debug a COM dll written in C++ from with an mstest run (Visual Studio 2008).  All projects are in the same solution. 3 Projects: C++ COM dll, VB.NET WinForms App, C# MSTest Project.

If I run a VB.NET Forms application I can successfully break and step into the COM dll.  Breakpoints set in the C++ work correctly.

The problem comes when trying to break and step into from with an MSTest debug session.  I can break in the C# test code.  However, from within mstest, I cannot step into the COM dll.  The breakpoint set in the C++ also never gets hit.  The debug into unmanaged code checkbox is checked in the project debug properties.

Tried so far:

1. Disabling Test Deployment: no effect
2. Added a unit test to the VB.NET forms app.  When running that as a
   unit test, it does not break or step into either, so it isn't a
   difference in project or reference.
3. Tried attaching to the vstesthost process from the COM DLL's
   properties, but get an error: "Unable to attach.  An attempt was
   made to perform an   initialization operation when initialization
   has already been completed."

Has anyone encountered issues with this in MSTest?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can't step from managed code into unmanaged code.  Be sure to enable unmanaged debugging with Project + Properties, Debug tab and to set a breakpoint in the COM code.

Comment: I have already enabled the unmanaged debugging in the MSTest project, but I am still not able to get a breakpoint to catch in the COM code when debugging under C# MSTest.  However, I can actually step into the COM code from the VB.NET WinForms test app when the unmanaged debugging is enabled in that project...if I could get the breakpoint to catch in the COM code as opposed to stepping in, that would be fine as well.

Comment: It isn't very clear what might cause your problem.  But do it the other way around, debug your C++ project.  Setup the debugger to start mstest.exe

Comment: Thanks for your response again.  I have tried starting the debugger through my C++ project with the mstest.exe and vstesthost.exe, but it simply starts and then stops again...not sure what to do there.

Comment: One helpful note: I just ported the solution to Visual Studio 2010 and the breakpoints in the COM code now catch when debugging through MSTest.  Maybe this is not possible in 2008...if you have any suggestions, please let me know.  Hopefully we will be switching everything over to 2010 sooner than later :)

Answer (score 0):

I am now able to debug into the C++ COM code through MSTest.  It seems to be an issue with the button used to run the test.  I have found consistently that when running the test using the "Debug Tests in Current Context" button through either the toolbar or menu, I cannot debug into the C++ COM code.  However, once the test appears in the Test Results window and I run using the "Debug Checked Tests" button in the toolbar of the Test Results window, I am able to debug into the C++ COM code successfully...

I have no idea why this is, but the only thing I have modified (and changed back) while doing this was the Solution platform, but the above statement holds true in both .NET and Mixed Platforms modes.